# SQL query for price

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with columns date and price
Can I find rows where the price was more than X percent from the previous price?

My table is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`prices` (

  `id` INT NOT NULL,

  `date` DATE NULL,

  `price` FLOAT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))

ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: can you tell query you already make and the schema of the table

Comment: attached it now

Answer (score 3):

you want the lead() and lag() functions (one looks to the row above, and the other to the row below).  (Here's an [example](https://www.got-it.ai/solutions/sqlquerychat/sql-help/data-query/mysql-lag-function-and-lead-function-querychat/))

For instance:

```sql
select * from (
        select [date], [price], lag([price],1,0) over (order by date) as lagged_price
        from your_table
) sub
where lagged_price / price > X -- here x would be 1.2 if you want it to be at least 20% greater
```